# How can I automatically escape data in views with Kohana 2 or KO3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

What's the best way to escape data from Models or Controllers to easily and safely display them in views. It seems kind of overkill to use **html::specialchars($varname)** for every data variable. It can also cause problems if a programmer forgets to "escape" data.

I've also encountered problems escaping ORM objects within loops.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the [Twig](http://github.com/ThePixelDeveloper/kohana-twig) module gimpe has suggested and by default it automatically escapes all data. You might also want to look into [Kostache](http://github.com/zombor/KOstache). It's a class based view system that does automatic escaping.

Regarding your comment:

> Is there a way to do this directly from the Model

You don't want to escape the data here because HTML escaped data doesn't make sense in all output formats, eg: JSON and XML.

Do the escaping at the view level.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is using a templating engine like Twig for the views. (see KO3 module http://github.com/ThePixelDeveloper/kohana-twig)

Then you simply need to load the Escaper extension:

> Twig_Extension_Escaper: Adds automatic output-escaping and the possibility to escape/unescape blocks of code.

Ref.: http://www.twig-project.org/book/03-Twig-for-Developers

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly from the Model